# My photos have the same blotch on them

Tags: canon

I have a Canon Rebel XT camera.  The photos take all have light brown blotches on them in the same area. Is this something a professional photographer store can repair?

Comment: Without some examples it is impossible to begin to diagnose what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Without seeing images, my first guess is dust on the sensor because it is common and can have an effect that could be described that way. Cleaning the sensor is probably worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This camera model allows you to remove the lens and replace it with another.  This lens interchange ability is a valued feature. The downside is, when the lens is removed, dust and other debris can enter and some will settle on the protective cover glass over the image sensor located at the rear of the camera body.

Should this rubbish remain, when a picture is being taken, the debris will block light thus casting their shadow on the image sensor. This shows up as a blemish such as what you have described. You prove this is so. Take a picture of something mundane like the blue sky or a white wall. Take several at different f-number settings. The shadow of the debris shadow will be hard sharp at tiny aperture settings and soft and out-of-focus at larger large aperture setting.

First try to blow off the debris by removing the lens and using a rubble ball blower, puff some air aimed at the surface of the cover glass. Check to see if this did the deed. If not, your camera has a sensor cleaning routine which you can access through the menu.  Sometimes we must be more aggressive when we clean the sensor cover glass. You can search the web for various ways. If you wish, take the camera to a photo shop or one-hour developing shop, they will help you clean your sensor.

Comment: Dust spots are the shadows falling on the sensor from dust on the cover glass a few mm in front of the sensor. Spots from shadows don't usually appear brown, they appear to be various shades of gray. This is probably something else.

Comment: @ Michael Clark - Probably what appears brown vs. what is black is in the eye of the beholder and the view screen / monitor settings. Probably these artifices are the shadows of debris. The fact that you think otherwise is valid.